# Finding an imperfect finite difference set for large N

Tags: additive-combinatorics, difference-sets

I want to find a set of integers $N$ for which there always exists a pair of numbers $(a, b)$ both $\in N$ such that $a-b = x$ for all $0<x<2^{32}$.

Obviously one possible set N is all the numbers from $0$ to $2^{32}$, but I believe the problem is solvable with a much smaller set, but I am at a loss how to find such a set in a computationally feasible way (ie. not a brute force search).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructions of small set with big difference set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168079/constructions-of-small-set-with-big-difference-set)